# Is this a 'dead code' i.e. is it just redundant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tostring

I came across this code snippet in our code base:

```js
function initDoughnutChart(target) {
  var labels = $(target).data("labels").toString().split(",");
  var dataString = $(target).data("chart-data").toString();
  // single-entry values
  if (typeof dataString === 'number') {
    dataString = dataString.toString();
  }
  var data = dataString.split(",");
  ...
```

Am I right to think the **if** statement is redundant as `dataString` is initialised to the value `<something>.<something>.toString()` thus it will (always?) have a type of `'string'` (unless its initialisation throws but then the **if** won't be reached at all).

Comment: you check against number not string right?

Comment: @gavgrif but what if the data attribute in question is not present on the passed `target` element? `null.toString()` and `undefined.toString()` would stop execution of the function.

Comment: @gavgrif jQuery's `.data()` can return things that aren't strings, but it's pretty safe to assume that `.data(something).toString()` will either produce a string or throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right. The only way I can see `datastring` as a `number` would be to have a custom `toString` defined somewhere else in the code (and I see no reason why).

Of course, there are other caveats in the code, like the fact that `$(target).data("labels").` will not work if `target` is undefined.